# Minimum of $\sum_{l=0}^{n} \frac{1}{(l!)^2((n-l)!)^2} x^{2l} (1-x)^{2(n-l)} $.

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, analysis

$\forall n \in \mathbf{N}$, prove that the function $f(x)=\sum_{l=0}^{n} \frac{1}{(l!)^2((n-l)!)^2} x^{2l} (1-x)^{2(n-l)} $ attains its minimum at $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

Now it suffices to prove that
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{l=0}^{n} \binom{n}{l}^2 (x+y)^{2l} (x-y)^{2(n-l)} = \sum_{l=0}^{n} \binom{2l}{l} \binom{2(n-l)}{n-l} x^{2l}y^{2(n-l)}
\end{equation*}

Comment: It is enough to show that $f(x)$ is a convex function fulfilling $f(x)=f(1-x)$.

Comment: Can you be more specific, I plotted $f(x)$ when $n$ is small and found what you said quite right.

Comment: The size of $n$ does not matter: $f(x)$ is convex and $f(x)=f(1-x)$ follows from reindexing $l\mapsto n-l$. A convex *and* symmetric function with respect to $x=\frac{1}{2}$ clearly attains its minimum at such a point.

Comment: Yeah, I just want to know how to prove its convexity.

Comment: Hey, can you give some hint or sketch of the proof? Thank you.

Comment: It seems that we have $$\sum_{l=0}^{n} \left( \binom{n}{l} (x+y)^l (x-y)^{n-l} \right)^2 = \sum_{l=0}^{n} \binom{2l}{l}\binom{2n-2l}{n-l} x^{2l}y^{2n-2l}. $$ I have no good idea to prove this, but once we assume this, then plugging $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and $y = \frac{r}{2}$ shows that $$ f\left(\frac{1+r}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \sum_{l=0}^{n} \binom{2l}{l}\binom{2n-2l}{n-l} r^{2l} $$ is convex and has the unique minimum at $r = 0$.

Comment: Ok, now I'm trying to prove it. Thank you.

Comment: @SangchulLee Your combinatorial identity is equivalent to this \begin{equation*}  \sum_{n,m=0}^{\infty} \tbinom{n+m}{n} ^ 2 (x+y)^{2n} (x-y)^{2m} = (1-4x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}} (1-4y^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}                                                                                                                           \end{equation*}

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio Thanks for your answer in that question. Now this is also settled.

Comment: @MartinChow: oh oh, a single answer serving two questions, I am proud of it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to minimize the function $f(x)=\sum_{l=0}^{n} \frac{1}{(l!)^2((n-l)!)^2} x^{2l} (1-x)^{2(n-l)} $.

Let $y = 2x(1-x)$. For any range of $x$, we have $y\leq 1/2$ , with $y=1/2$ achieved when $x=1/2$.

Consider the following integral:
$$g(y)=\int_0^{2\pi}\left(1-y(1-\cos \theta)\right)^n d\theta$$
I could show that
$$g(y) = (n!)^2 f(x)$$
(see further below for proof of above)
Since $(1-\cos \theta)\in [0,2]$, $g(y)$ is a linear combination of monotonic non-increasing  functions. So, $g(y)$ monotonic non-increasing in $y$. Since the range of $y$ is $(-\infty,1/2]$, $g(y)$ is minimized at $y=1/2$. 
This means that $f(x)$ is minimized at $x=1/2$.

**Proof for $g(y) = (n!)^2 f(x)$:**

To show the above, I considered a random variable $X$ that takes values in the set $\{0,1,...,n\}$ with following probability mass function.$$P[X=k]= p_k= \frac {n!}{k! (n-k)!}x^k (1-x)^{n-k}$$ Clearly, $\sum_k P[X=k] = \sum_k p_k  = (x+1-x)^n=1$ so this is a valid probability mass function.

Note that $f(x) = \frac 1 {(n!)^2} \sum_k p_k^2$, so our interest is in $\sum_k p_k^2$. Consider the following transform: $$ \phi(\theta) = \sum_k p_k e^{j\theta k} = (x e^{j\theta} + 1-x)^n $$
This $\phi(\theta)$ is the moment generating function of $X$ evaluated at $j\theta$.

Clearly, $$\phi(\theta) \phi(-\theta) = (1-y+y\cos \theta)^n$$
Interestingly, this gives an expression for  $\sum_k p_k^2$ as follows:
$$\phi(\theta) \phi(-\theta) = \left(\sum_k p_k e^{j\theta k}\right) \left(\sum_k p_k e^{-j\theta k}\right) = \sum_k p_k^2 + 2 \sum_l \sum_{m>l} p_l p_m cos\left((m-l)\theta\right)$$

We can get rid of the pesky cos terms by integration.
$$g(y)=\int_0^{2\pi}\left(1-y + y \cos \theta\right)^n d\theta = \sum_k p_k^2 $$
So, $g(y) = (n!)^2 f(x)$ as promised.

Comment: That's amazing! Thanks for your beautiful probability proof. In fact, this problem originates from stochastic process.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
n &> 0  \text{.}  \\
f'(1/2) &= \left. \sum_{l=0}^{n} \frac{1}{(l!)^2((n-l)!)^2} \left( (2l)x^{2l-1}(1-x)^{2(n-l)} - 2(n-l)x^{2l}(1-x)^{2(n-l)-1} \right) \right|_{x = 1/2}  \\
    &= \sum_{l=0}^{n} \frac{1}{(l!)^2((n-l)!)^2} \left( (2l)(1/2)^{2l-1}(1/2)^{2(n-l)} - 2(n-l)(1/2)^{2l}(1/2)^{2(n-l)-1}  \right)  \\
    &= (1/2)^{2n-1}\sum_{l=0}^{n} \frac{1}{(l!)^2((n-l)!)^2} \left( (2l) - 2(n-l) \right)  \\
    &= 0  \text{.}  \\
f(x) &= \sum_{l=0}^{n} \frac{1}{(l!)^2((n-l)!)^2} x^{2l} (1-x)^{2(n-l)}  \\
    &= \frac{(1-x)^{2n}}{(n!)^2} + \frac{x^{2n}}{(n!)^2} + \sum_{l=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{(l!)^2((n-l)!)^2} x^{2l} (1-x)^{2(n-l)} \text{.}  \\
f''(x) &= \frac{2n(2n-1)\left(x^{2(n-1)} + (1-x)^{2(n-1)}\right)}{(n!)^2} + \\
     {}&+ \sum_{l=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{(l!)^2((n-l)!)^2} x^{2(l-1)}(1-x)^{2(n-l-1)} \left( 2n(2n-1)x^2 - 4l(2n-1)x + 2l(2l-1)\right)  \\
    &> 0 + \sum_{l=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{(l!)^2((n-l)!)^2} x^{2(l-1)}(1-x)^{2(n-l-1)} \frac{2l(l-n)}{n}  \\
    &\geq 0  \text{.}  \blacksquare
\end{align*}

Comment: Sorry, but could you please check your calculation? I think the $2l(l-1)$ in the third line from the end should be $2l(l-1)$, and $2n(2n-1)x^2 - 4l(2n-1)x + 2l(2l-1)$ attains its minimum $\frac{2l(l-n)}{n}$ at $x=\frac{l}{n}$.

Comment: @MartinChow : You seem to have replicated my error w.r.t "$2l(\mathbf{2}l-1)$".  But I agree.  And while it takes its minimum at $x = 1/n$, that is useless for the inequality -- we need that its minimum value is $2l(n-l)/n > 0$.

Comment: @MartinChow : Okay...  No idea why my brain wants to swap the $l$ and the $n$ in that minimum.  Both times.  Meh.

Comment: @MartinChow : Do you find any further deficiencies in this demonstration that the only possible minimum of $f(x)$ is at $x=1/2$?